# Can someone explain the strange increase in performance of MPI_reduce when I increase number of nodes on Cray

Tags: performance, mpi

I was trying to do analysis of performance on an MPI program to add two vectors on a CRAY @ my college, but I noticed a strange results for the performance of `MPI_Reduce` when I set it to run on 96 processors. Each node on CRAY has 24 cores.

Here is the code:

```c
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define SIZE 331776 // (24^4) elements in each vector


double get_wall_time(){

        struct timeval time;
        gettimeofday(&time,NULL);
        return (double)time.tv_sec + (double)time.tv_usec/1000000;
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
int source, numtasks;
int rank;

double time_begin,time_end,totalTime;
long int i,j;
double reduceTime,productTime; 
float a[SIZE],b[SIZE]; // declaring vectors to be multiplied
float dot_product = 0; // final result of dot product

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);

if(SIZE % numtasks  == 0){
        long int loc_blockSize = SIZE/numtasks; // block size for local buffers
        float loc_buff_a[loc_blockSize];   // local buffer a for each processor 
        float loc_buff_b[loc_blockSize];   // local buffer b for each processor
        float loc_dot[loc_blockSize];      // number of local dot products 
        source = 0;            // process 0 where all the data exists

        float result[loc_blockSize];       // results on the process 0
        if(rank == source){
            for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){    // assigning random values to both a and b vector
                a[i] = i;
                b[i] = i;               
            }
        }   

        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD); // wait till process 0 assigns value to a and b


        /* calculating scatter time*/
        time_begin = get_wall_time(); 
        MPI_Scatter(&a,loc_blockSize,MPI_FLOAT,&loc_buff_a,loc_blockSize,MPI_FLOAT,source,MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
        MPI_Scatter(&b,loc_blockSize,MPI_FLOAT,&loc_buff_b,loc_blockSize,MPI_FLOAT,source,MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
        time_end = get_wall_time(); 

        totalTime = time_end-time_begin;
        printf("rank = %d and scatter time:\n%f\n",rank,totalTime);
        //scatter time ends----------------------------

        /* calculating product time*/
        time_begin = get_wall_time(); 

        for(i=0; i<loc_blockSize; i++)
        {
            loc_dot[i]= loc_buff_a[i] * loc_buff_b[i];

        /* //remove this commment to see the result of dot product at each processor
        printf("rank= %d Local values:a[%d]= %f b[%d]=%f Dot: %f  \n",rank,i,loc_buff_a[i],i,loc_buff_b[i],loc_dot[i]);
        */

        }

        time_end  = get_wall_time(); 
        totalTime = time_end-time_begin;
        printf("rank = %d and product time:\n%f\n",rank,totalTime);
        //product time ends----------------------------

        /* calculating reduce time*/
        time_begin = get_wall_time(); 


        MPI_Reduce(&loc_dot,&result,loc_blockSize,MPI_FLOAT,MPI_SUM,source,MPI_COMM_WORLD); 

        if(rank == 0){  
            for(i=0;i<loc_blockSize;i++){
                dot_product = dot_product + result[i];
            }
            printf("The result is: %f\n",dot_product);
        }

        time_end  = get_wall_time(); 
        totalTime = time_end-time_begin;
        printf("rank = %d and reduction time:\n%f\n",rank,totalTime);
        //reduce time ends--------------------

}// check-divisibility ends---------------

  else {
      printf("The vector size(=%d) is not divisible by number of %d processors\n",SIZE,numtasks);
  }
MPI_Finalize();

}
```

The results of running it with different number of processors:

[image]

[image]

Comment: From which rank are you reporting the time? If it's rank 0 as I read your code the reduce time is not only for the MPI, which you would expect to increase, but also the local dot_product which is DECREASING as the number of processes increases. Also If you really are worried about these very short times I'd add a barrier before the starting call to get_wall_time as load imbalance or process jitter or similar could markedly affect the results.

Comment: Yes,the reported time is for rank 0. All the results are satisfactory and according to my expectation but the value of reduction with 96 processors is kind of weird. I tried running it multiple times ,but it's always less than reduction time for 72 processors. 
Shouldn't the reduction time increase along with increase in data transferred from different nodes(Each nodes has 24 cores) on to rank 0?

Comment: Well to be sure I would, as I say above, time only the reduce and put a barrier before the start of the timer. Otherwise you aren't measuring only what you want to measure

Comment: This cannot possibly be the real code since 100000 is not divisible by either 72 or 96 and hence it should simply give the error. But even if the size is 100000 elements, note that going from 72 ranks to 96 ranks cuts the message size to `100000/96*sizeof(float)`, which is less than 512 bytes. There usually are several algorithms that implement `MPI_Reduce` and they are selected based on the message size and the number of ranks. Check the Cray documentation on how to fix the algorithm (if user selection is possible at all).

Comment: Thanks Hristo, for pointing out the mistake. Actually I had added an older version of my code. I used 24^4 element for performance testing

Comment: Again, with so many elements, going from 72 to 96 ranks decreases the message size from over 16 KiB to less than 16 KiB, hence a change in the algorithm might explain the observed performance increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar performance problem while working on Cray for my research project and I discussed it with my advising professor. One of the reason for this result could be the optimization when more than specific number of nodes are utilized.This optimization could result into better performance than 2 or 3 nodes although it should have been worst.

Try using different number of nodes (i.e increase the process in multiple of 24) beyond four nodes and check the results.

You can try mpi_barrier but it would not change anything since the result only gets printed after all the process are done calculating the dot product.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know how I can stop that optimization from happening?

Comment: You should probably ask the system admin, he is the best person to answer that :)